# My winget isn't working properly, how can I solve it?

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, winget

I use my winget to install most of my programs, but it's not working properly. Any command I use, whether it's a simple list, doesn't load and I get the following screen:

[image]

```
PS C:\Users\lucas> winget install --id Git.Git
  -
PS C:\Users\lucas>
```

And it stays there until I close the window. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

I recently reinstalled Windows 11 to repair some disk errors. The Disko error was fixed, but there is this issue that doesn't work. Test, in cmd and powershell, in both it's the same situation. How can I solve it?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Lucas. SO is a place where programers help programmers make source code work. This question is not about source code. This question is about using a program so is not on-topic for SO as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with versions of WinGet lower than 1.6.3482. The root cause of the issue is the CDN. Microsoft has retired the original CDN which was hardcoded into earlier versions of WinGet.

According to the [Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli/tree/master/doc/troubleshooting#executing-winget-exits-with-no-message), installing the latest release of WinGet using `Add-AppxPackage https://aka.ms/getwinget` should resolve the issue